# How to compare 2 lists and get only some specific values?

Tags: python, list

I have this problem that I can't solve.
I don't want to use numpy or other libraries, I just want to understand the logic but I can't solve it.
So I have 2 lists:

```
t1 = [(2, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1)]
t2 = [(2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 1)]
```

And I want to get this:

```
lista = [(2, 1), (5, 1)]
```

I use this loop to select the values to put in the list:

```
counter = len(t1)
c = 0
print(t1[c][0])

lista = []
for e in range(counter):
    if t1[c][0] == t2[c][0]:
        lista.append(t1)
        c += 1
        
print(lista)
```

As a result I get this thing:

```
[[(2, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1)]]
```

But I have tried them all (<, >, <=, >=, I think) and I can't get the correct values selected.

In my opinion what this code should do is compare the values in t1[0][0], i.e. (2) with t2[0][0], i.e. (2). In theory if they are not equal it should not put anything in the list.
Okay for the first 2 and 2 is correct, but the second 5 and 3? and the third 7 and 5?
Why the hell does he add them?

Don't suggest set(). I'm stubborn and would like to solve with lists and understand the logic.

Can someone let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what your goal is. It looks like an intersection of the list, i.e. return those elements that are in both lists. However, that is only true for `(5, 1)`. In addition, it is not a union either. So set operations are out... We could come up with various ways to produce the result (e.g. first entry of the tuple must be `2` or `5` while the second entry has to be `1`). But how would that help?

Comment: "And I want to get this:" Why? What is the underlying logic? If I say that I think the answer should be something else, why would I be wrong? "Don't suggest set(). I'm stubborn and would like to solve with lists and understand the logic." We generally try to answer *practical* questions here. "Why the hell does he add them?" Well, in your own words, where the code says `lista.append(t1)`, what do you expect will be the value of `t1`? Therefore, what changes in `lista`? Did you try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code?

Comment: Try to state what you try to achieve - the *goal*?

Comment: It seems like you want `(5,1)` to be added to the result because it appears in both lists. But how can this happen if you compare `(5, 1)` to `(3, 1)`, and then `(7, 1)` to `(5, 1)`? And why should `(2, 1)` be added to the result? I don't think the second list contains that.

Comment: Okay, actually these lists were derived from 2 separate dictionaries on an operation that allows me to derive the Maximum Common Denominator.
The MCD takes as values those with lower frequency and excludes those that are not in both lists. 
The first value of the tuple (2, ) is the Prime Factor while ( ,1) and the power elevation so the final operation will be, for example 2**1.
So all this I need is to exclude those prime factors that are greater. I hope I have clarified...:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appended the whole list to the new list, that's why you get the wrong answer you want:

```
lista.append(t1)
```

This will append the whole list t1 to the new lista. Just change it to t1[c] then you will not get all the items.

However, this will still only compare item with same index, so it will still be wrong.
This is actually a search problem and you can search more online. Here is a simple solution to achieve what I believe you want.

```
t1 = [(2, 1), (5, 1), (7, 1)]
t2 = [(2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 1)]

lista = []
for i in range(len(t1)):
    j = 0
    while (j < len(t2)):
        if t1[i][0] == t2[j][0]:
            lista.append(t1[i])
            break
        j += 1
        
print(lista)
```

PS: please explain your end goal and question clearly next time so we can look at it easier and answer faster. We don't need to know your thought process if it doesn't relate to the question.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Thank you.
Sorry for the articulate but unclear explanation, but I have only been learning a programming language for a few weeks and I have quite a bit of difficulty.
Will try to be more precise, I hope, next time